# Opening PDF from browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, pdf, base64

I need to open a pdf that i receive in a base64 string.
I was using the following line to open it

```
window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + string64);
```

It works with chrome and Firefox, but Internet-Explorer cant open it. 
Is there a workaround for this? From what i read, IE does not fully support base64. Is there another way to do this, that will work on every browser?